# Bootstrap grid: Is this correct to replace col-xs-6 + col-xs-6 with col-xs-12+ (col-xs-6 & display:none)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm curious if it is correct to replace

```
<div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
```

with

```
<div class="col-xs-12">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-6" style="display:none;">...</div>
```

with javascript?

All I need is to hide the second div and display 100% for the first div properly and **by javascript.** what is actually done. The question is if it is a proper way from Twitter Bootstrap prospective.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment your vote. Do you know the answer on this question? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but I wonder why you want to do this. Maybe it's a wrong answer to a problem you may solve differently. As answered by deepa if your point is to hide the 2nd div if the screen is too small, you don't need javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap by itself is a responsive framework. You can achieve the above result without using Javascript.

Instead of writing

```
<div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
```

You can write

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">...</div>
```

Here you can use sm, md and lg for small, medium and large layouts respectively.

When your screen gets resized to xs, the above code displays 100% of the first div and the second div is hidden.

This is a better approach when using Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you. However, I need to change classes not because of a small or large screen, but because of another specification that come from the javascript code.